# Why do I need Tag in GitHub in Android Studio?

Tags: git, android-studio, github

I use Github in my Android Studio.

A:  In Figure 1, the history of commit such as "Submit 1", "Submit 2" are listed in Commit Message area, it's very clear. I don't know why I need Tag. What can Tag do?

B:  I find that another Tag command display in Git-> Tag, you can see them in Figure 2A and Figure 2B, could you tell me what are different between the two Tag command?

**Figure 1**

[image]

**Figure 2A**

[image]

**Figure 2B**

[image]

Answer (score 4, accepted):

### What is tagging, in Git?

`7ed4814` - imagine if you see this in git.

What on earth is that meant to mean?

It means nothing to a human being. But if you have a 'tag', it allows you to give that particular commit a name. And names are very understandable / rememberable to human beings:

`7ed4814 (v1.2)`

ok, this commit means version `1.2`. sweeeet!

**For example:**

Imagine you have a huge repository, 100s of commits, and many different versions. Which commit was version 1.1 again? Which commit was version 1.2? It's easy to find out if you have tagged those commits:

`$ git show v1.2`

```
tag v1.2
Tagger: Scott Chacon <schacon@gee-mail.com>
Date:   Mon Feb 9 15:32:16 2009 -0800
```

That was a little too easy.

Here is a link to the documentation which explains this in further detail: https://git-scm.com/book/en/v2/Git-Basics-Tagging

Lastly, I don't think there is any difference between the two methods to create a tag, nor do i know for sure whether android studio does a light weight tag, or an annotated tag. I don't have android studio, so I cannot confirm this 100%.

Comment: They're identical, but I think the one in the VCS dropdown covers the latest commit, or requires selecting one. The function itself is the same.

Answer (score 3):

Tags are a simple aspect of Git, they allow you to identify specific release versions of your code. You can think of a tag as a branch that doesn't change. Once it is created, it loses the ability to change the history of commits.

**Two Types of Git Tags**

There are two types of tags in Git: annotated and lightweight. Both of them will allow you to refer to a specific commit in a repository, but they differ in the amount of metadata they can store.

**Annotated Tags**

Annotated tags store extra metadata such as author name, release notes, tag-message, and date as full objects in the Git database. All this data is important for a public release of your project.

Tags can also include a more descriptive tag-message or annotation much like a commit message when you are about to merge. Usually, this is achieved by using (-a for annotation):

```
$ git tag -a v1.0.0
```

Executing this command you will create a new annotated tag identified with version v1.0.0. The command will then open up your commit editor so that you can fill up the metadata.

In case you wanted to add a tag-message you can pass the `-m` option, this is a method similar to `git commit -m`.

```
$ git tag -a v1.0.0 -m "Releasing version v1.0.0"
```

**Lightweight Tags**

Lightweight tags are the simplest way to add a tag to your git repository because they store only the hash of the commit they refer to. They are created with the absence of the -a, -s, or -m options and do not contain any extra information.

[According to BitBucket](https://www.atlassian.com/git/tutorials/inspecting-a-repository/git-tag): Lightweight tags are essentially "bookmarks" to a commit, they are just a name and a pointer to a commit, useful for creating quick links to relevant commits.

To create a new lightweight tag execute the following command:

```
$ git tag v1.0.0
```

[For more information, refer here](https://dev.to/neshaz/a-tutorial-for-tagging-releases-in-git-147e)